# Waiting for certain information in a NetworkStream object

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networkstream

I've spent the past few days trying to read from a NetworkStream object using both the BeginRead and the Read methods, however both methods have been giving me difficulties and are unreliable it seems

The first, "Read" required me to sleep the thread and expected the correct data to be present when the sleep finished.
Like so:

```
cmd = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(CommandString + "\r");
ns.Write(cmd, 0, cmd.Length);
Thread.Sleep(5000);
int _bytes = ns.Read(output, 0, output.Length);
responseOutput = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(output, 0, _bytes);
Console.Write(responseOutput);
```

This worked 80% of the time because the latency to the server fluctuated throughout the day, I've also tried the method below which i feel is poorly constructed, what would be the most efficient way to go about polling for data that matches a set of conditions that doesn't burn the CPU nor waste time?

```
bool connection_check = false;
String[] new_connection_array = new String[] { "processed successfully", "invalid", "Command not recognised. Check validity and spelling" };

do
{
    int view_bytes = ns.Read(output, 0, output.Length);
    responseOutput += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(output, 0, view_bytes);

    foreach (String s in new_connection_array)
         if (responseOutput.IndexOf(s) > -1)
             connection_check = true;

} while (connection_check == false);
```

Thanks in advance

Edit:

```
 public bool SendCommandAndWait(Byte[] command, Regex condition)
        {
            if (callback == null)
            {
                SendCommand(command);

                callback = ar =>
                {
                    int bytesEnd = ns.EndRead(ar);
                    int bytes = bytesEnd;

                    // Process response
                    responseOutput += System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(output, 0, bytes);

                    // Check if we can return
                    if (condition.IsMatch(responseOutput))
                        return; // Yes, there is a match... return from the async call
                    else // No match, so loop again
                        ns.BeginRead(output, 0, output.Length, callback, null); // Call the loop again
                };
                ns.BeginRead(output, 0, output.Length, callback, null);
            }

            // Because the callback is fired into a different thread and the program continues, we need to loop here so the program doesn't continue without us
            do
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                //Console.WriteLine(responseOutput);
            } while (!condition.IsMatch(responseOutput));

            if (condition.IsMatch(responseOutput))
            {
                callback = null;
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;

        }
```

Comment: This question is asked daily. TCP sockets offer a stream of data, not messages. You don't need Thread.Sleep(), you need an application protocol to determine message boundaries so you know when you have received an entire message. Don't use sockets if you don't have a very compelling reason, use a higher-level concept like SOAP through WCF.

Comment: I'm aware that they don't work like messages which is why i sort of "collect" the stream until the data matches a condition, However this program will be running headless, as a service on a server and will be contacting a Telnet client of which i don't have control over. Afaik, working with Sockets is the only way to go, not to mention a huge design change isn't on the cards

Comment: @CodeCaster, then create or find a question that can be used as a target to close them as duplicates.   I think a question is needed for each platform so as to allow good example code.

Comment: @Ian there are hundreds, if not thousands of questions on this very subject for C# alone. I cannot find a proper canonical duplicate and can't be bothered at the moment to write one.

Answer (score 0):

BeginRead will let you define an action that is executed when beginread is finished.  Note that this is not the same as when you have read everything you want to read.  That is why read returns the number of bytes read.  If you expect to read 20 bytes and get 10, then you will need to read 10 more bytes.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.beginread(v=vs.110).aspx :

> The BeginRead method reads as much data as is available, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter.
>
> If you want the original thread to block after you call the BeginRead method, use the WaitOne method.

Comment: Hi Vegahyo, i've already tried to use the BeginRead method (see edit) but the callback does not always return on the condition specified, any ideas? Thanks

Comment: You need to wait on it.  But remember that read does not always read the bytes you want it to read, you need to check if the number of bytes read equals what you expect.
Pseudo code:  

    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    BeginRead(blah,blah,blah,callback)
    allDone.WaitOne();

    void callback()
    {
     allDone.Set();
    }